# Running a docker image with user and group 1000

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I would like to run my image with my user, when I do `echo $(id -u)` and `echo gid=$(id -g)` I get `1000` in both.

Basically I do:

```
docker run -u 1000:1000 --rm -e .....
```

During my local image running process I write some files in my machine, but when I see the permissions and owner in this file `(ls -l)` I get:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11399 feb 22 22:33 sresult.json
```

It seems like the owner is still the root use, not sure why if I am passing the user 1000 to the run command.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] that shows more of the setup?  Does the container setup do anything to switch user IDs on its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should have a binded volumen to your path where you expect written files to be same as your host machine.

Try adding [Bind Mounts volumen flag](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/app --workdir /app  -u $(id -u):$(id -g) ...
```

Notice `-v $PWD:/app`, and the optional `--workdir /app` for container to start at that /app location.